# How to Send VB.Net DataGridView information in Grid/Table Form via email

Tags: vb.net

Can any body help me out in VB.Net [Using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express] that how to send DataGridView [Records/Data has been fetched from Database] information via email using VB.Net. I am able to send email with DataGrid information but not in Grid/Table form. Below is sample Code:

```
Private Sub btnGUIEmail_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGUIEmail.Click

    Dim html As String = String.Empty
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage

    mail.Subject = "test email"
    mail.To.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    mail.From = New MailAddress("X@gmail.com")

    Dim strAccount_No, strClient_Name As String

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

     strAccount_No = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
     strClient_Name = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value.ToString

      strMailBody += strAccount_No & "     " & strClient_Name & vbCrLf
        Mail.Body = strMailBody
     Next

   Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.X.com")
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("X@gmail.com", "X")
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
    MsgBox("Email Sent")


End Sub
```

Can any body help me out in VB.Net [Using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express] that how to send DataGridView [Records/Data has been fetched from Database] information via email using VB.Net. I am able to send email with DataGrid information but not in Grid/Table form. Below is sample Code:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it in table format, you have to create the information in the html format using the table tags.

for eg.

```
mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
mail.Body = "this is my test email body.<br><b>this part is in bold</b>"
```

Just go through below links, it may help you to understand how?

http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx?cat=6

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-and-send-HTML-Formatted-Emails-in-ASP.Net-using-C-and-VB.Net.aspx

I hope it will help you.. :)

Comment: Yes You are right but I am unable to implement HTML code in VB.Net as there are some errors with Blue Underline, like Mail.Body.Format = MailFormat.Html is not being implemented. Moreover, in the provided links code [mailMessage.From = New MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserName"))], ConfigurationManager is being highlighted with Blue Underline. Please Help to overcome this issue.

Comment: To use configuration manager, you have to manually add the reference of System.Configuration. And can you share your code where you are building html code, so that i can rectify the issue.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Hitesh, Now I am able to implemnt waht I wanted with the help of Command "Mail.IsBodyHtml = True", so now want to set Background and Foreground Color of Particular Columns and Rows. Please Help!

Comment: You just have to add styles to columns, for eg. <td style="background-color:red;color:yellow". Try this, and let me know, if you face any issue. If you are satisfied with the answer then vote the answer and also mark as complete ans below the voting.